# Not able to override the input value for Google Cloud Dataproc query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We are migrating our existing jobs from Hadoop to GCP Environment. So we have a requirement where we need to change existing beeline command to Cloud Dataproc. In Hadoop environment we were using following command to query a table in Hive:

```sh
beeline -u BEELINE_URL --hivevar HIVE_CORE_DB=$HIVE_CORE_DB --hivevar HIVE_CORE_TBL=$HIVE_CORE_TBL -f table.hql
```

The input file **table.hql** contains following information:

```sql
select count(*) from ${hivevar:HIVE_CORE_DB}${hivevar:HIVE_CORE_TBL};
```

When I am converting the same code for Cloud Dataproc command I am using the following command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=cluster_name --region=region_name --params HIVE_CORE_DB=$HIVE_CORE_DB --params HIVE_CORE_TBL=$HIVE_CORE_TBL --file=table.hql
```

And table.hql file again contains the same input as earlier i.e.

```
select count(*) from ${hivevar:HIVE_CORE_DB}${hivevar:HIVE_CORE_TBL};
```

However, I am not able to override the values of variable containing in input file **table.hql**.

Getting following error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:15 cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hivevar' in table name (state=42000,code=40000)
>
> TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying input values under separate `--params` flags, you need to use only one.

Try changing the

`--params HIVE_CORE_DB=$HIVE_CORE_DB --params HIVE_CORE_TBL=$HIVE_CORE_TBL`

part of you command to

`--params HIVE_CORE_DB=$HIVE_CORE_DB,HIVE_CORE_TBL=$HIVE_CORE_TBL`.